# Retrieving email by id and but throwing an error

Tags: email, soap-api, marketing-cloud, email-template, .net

I am trying to retrieving the email below code and returned as error using SAOP API (.NET). Is there any code issue here ? What is the the minimum input is required to retrieve email object ? I am passing email id (i.e. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) and email name (i.e. yyyyyyyyyyyyyy) as properties to the retrieve request object.

RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
rr.ObjectType = "Email";//required

rr.Properties = new string[] {"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","yyyyyyyyyyyyyy" };//required

APIObject[] Results;
String requestID;

String status = _exactTargetSoapApiClient.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out Results);

Email email2 = (Email)Results[0];

I am getting below error when I am trying to retrieve the email

Error: The Request Property(s) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,yyyyyyyyyyyyyy do not match with the fields of Email retrieve

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Thanks,
Rama

Comment: What exactly are you trying to retrieve? An outbound email envelope, an inbound envelope, a saved Fileattachment, savedDocumentAttachment, saved email, or a saved outbound email/envelope that's been sent? Its unclear what you're looking for and how you queried the ID? SOAP isn't my area, but there are many things you can get related to email and your code seems unclear as to what ID you're expecting to be returned. It looks to me like it's outbound, but outbound what (envelope or mail)?

Comment: What are the actual properties you are trying to use in `Properties` I don't think it's `"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [How to Retrieve an Email via the SOAP API](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_an_email_via_the_soap_api/) as a guide I'm thinking that your problem is that you haven't set up a SimpleFilterPart that would be attached to the RetriveRequest rr.

For example

```
        // Setting up a simple filter
        SimpleFilterPart sf = new SimpleFilterPart();
        sf.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
        sf.Property = "Name";
        sf.Value = new String[] { "Sample" };

        //Add Filter
        rr.Filter = sf;
```

This also is assuming that

```
_exactTargetSoapApiClient.Retrieve(…);
```

does the same thing as

```
SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
```

which it probably does.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. I was missing SimpleFilterPart.